# Malwarebytes informs me once every ~20 minutes that it's blocking something outgoing to www.tracknl.info

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, spyware, malwarebytes

The port changes, but the domain, IP, type, and process are all constant. I just want to know, is this normal/acceptable? What should I do about it?

I think this is just a trial of Malwarebytes and it's going to run out soon. In case it matters, I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 (SP1).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7k0X.jpg) are a couple of examples of the notifications I'm receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as I can tell from the pics, you have an extension in chrome that is trying to connect. You might look there.

Comment: Alright so I have just tried disabling each extension and waiting to see whether I still get that notification and it still happens. Do you know what else it might be?